# How to set a new handler in Apache2

Tags: c, apache, apache2

I made a module for Apache that serves every type of GET and HEAD requests. I compiled and enabled it with apxs. The Apache Service restart correctly and everything is fine. How can I put it inside the chain of a service request? I have to disable other modules in order to use my own?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Short answer is you have to register your handler by calling ap_hook_handler()... but there are things your handler must do.  Give this a read for some guidance: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/developer/modguide.html

Comment: The problem is the declaration inside httpd.conf or apache2.conf with AddHandler or SetHandler. I really don't understand how to use it...

Comment: Man  page for AddHandler http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler     Man page for SetHandler http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#sethandler